# When is an isogeny $F\colon A \rightarrow A$ a closed map?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties

Let $A$ be an abelian variety and $F\colon A \rightarrow A$ an isogeny. Is it a closed map?

Comment: An abelian variety is proper and separated (over the base field).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It follows from the following Lemma: Let $\phi:X \to Y$ and $\psi: Y \to Z$ be morphisms of varieties (so in particular separated), if $\psi \circ \phi$ is proper then $\phi$ is proper.

This implies that any morphism of varieties between proper varieties must itself be proper, hence closed.

Comment: Don't you mean "Let $\phi:X \to Y$ and $\psi: Y \to Z$ be morphisms of varieties; if $\psi \circ \phi$ is proper and if $\psi$ is separated, then $\phi$ is proper." (Corollary II.4.8. in Hartshorne) ? — This can be used because an abelian variety $Y$ is complete hence $Y \to \mathrm{Spec}(k)$ is separated.

Comment: Yes, thank you.